# How to interrupt a Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to create a smart TV using a Raspberry Pi 3B+. I plan on using Tkinter to create a GUI for the TV and flask to create a remote that can be accessed via a smartphone.

I plan on running Flask and call the Tkinter via a subprocess. The issue I'm facing is when I need to pause a video, for example. The Flask process must interrupt the Tkinter subprocess to pause the video. I can't seem to find any solutions to how this might be done. One idea I had was to send a keyboard interrupt and handle pause\play, but since other forms of interrupts are also required such as volume and seek, I will need multiple different interrupts with data such as seek time, etc as well.

How can this be achieved using python subprocesses?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send signals between two processes. You can probably use celery for that. Or use a simple sqlite database shared by both processes. the Flask process writes, the tkinter reads changes

Or look at this: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html